# installing ubuntu over windows7 - want to repartition and switch to UEFI

Tags: kubuntu, uefi, mbr

I've been given an old company laptop with a Windows 7 / CentOS dual boot setup - using MBR.  I want to wipe the whole thing and install Ubuntu under UEFI - but I want to create my own partition layout (essentially, a normal layout with a second, unused 'root' partition to install a future new Linux distro into without trashing the live one).

So is it sufficient to simply choose 'manual', delete everything that's there, and set up the partitions I want?  Will that also set up UEFI booting for me?  I assume I also have to tweak the BIOS to boot off of UEFI - it's currently set to legacy.  I'm typing from Ubuntu booted from a UEFI flash drive, so the BIOS can certainly handle it...

If it's not possible to do this in one step, can I just let Ubuntu 'take the whole disk' and then reinstall it after Ubuntu has done whatever magic it needs to do to convert to UEFI?

Comment: You can just do it via install; "Something else" lets you control partitioning (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) however personally I prefer setting up my partitions before hand, then just selecting them in the installer (refer @Nmath's answer).  I'd use `gparted` instead of `gnome-disks` Nmath uses; but that's just my choice.  You tagged Kubuntu, so it's "*KDE Partition Manager*" (instead of `gnome-disks`, Disks or `gparted`) and "*Something else*" is "*Manual Partition*" (*or wording like that*) in the installer.

Comment: If changing from legacy/MBR to UEFI/GPT setup, would change first, then install.

Comment: I also prefer gparted. With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. Depending on size of drive 100 to 500MB for ESP,  and if space not large just one ext4 partition for / (root). If larger drive then  30GB or so for / and rest for /home and/or data partition(s). UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

Don't over complicate this!  It's easier if you start with a clean slate.  Just format (erase) the disk prior to system installation:

- When booting from Ubuntu installation media, choose the "Try Ubuntu" option.
- Once you are in a live session, open the **Disks** application.
- Choose your disk on the left side column and then click the hamburger menu on the top right of the window and choose "**Format Disk...**"
- You can do a "Quick" erase and for "Partitioning" choose GPT.

  *(GPT is the partition scheme needed for UEFI installations)*

Once the disk is formatted as GPT, reboot the computer for the system installation or just use the installation link on the desktop in the live session.

As long as you are booting in UEFI mode from your motherboard BIOS and not "legacy" or "compatibility" modes, and your disk has a GPT partition scheme, the installation will proceed as a UEFI installation.

Comment: The KDE Partition Manager that comes up as 'Disks' on Kubuntu doesn't seem to have  a quick erase option.  Format also seems greyed on for the individual partitions - so is delete.

Comment: Use `sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility` in a terminal to install the application in the live session and you'll be able to use the Disks app.